# How To Instantiate ViewModel In A Data Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app

I'm new developer in WPF, universal apps, etc..

I created a view to display questions.

I have a QuestionsViewModel which exposes a Question collection. In the XAML, I use an ItemsControl to display the questions.

Now in the DataTemplate, I would like to use a user control to display the question, instantiate my QuestionViewModel, bind the current Question to it and set the view model as context of the user control. My problem is than {Binding} doesn't give me a Question, I have a Binding object :/

Should i do that way ?
How to get the current Question in the ViewModel ?

---

Code

```
public class Question : AEntity, IQuestion
{
    public Question(String title, String answer) : base()
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Answer = answer;
    }


    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private String description;

    public QuestionsViewModel()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Question> questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
        questions.CollectionChanged += Questions_CollectionChanged;
        Questions = questions;
        AddQuestionCommand = new AddQuestionCommand(Questions);
        AddQuestionCommand.Execute(null);//add a question for test
    }

    private void Questions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Description = String.Format("{0} question(s)", Questions.Count);
    }

    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; private set; }

    public ICommand AddQuestionCommand { get; private set; }

    public String Description {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            onPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
}

public class QuestionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Question question;

    public QuestionViewModel()
    {
    }

    public Question Question { get; set; }

}
```

Questions view

```
<UserControl  x:Class="Question_Answer.View.Control.QuestionsControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:model="using:Question_Answer.Model"
xmlns:uc="using:Question_Answer.View.Control"
xmlns:vm="using:Question_Answer.ViewModel.Control"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:QuestionsViewModel Description="view description">  </vm:QuestionsViewModel>        
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ItemsControl Name="Questions" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Question">
                <uc:QuestionItemControl>
                    <uc:QuestionItemControl.DataContext>
                        <vm:QuestionViewModel Question="{Binding}" />
                    </uc:QuestionItemControl.DataContext>
                </uc:QuestionItemControl>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Question user control

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Question_Answer.View.Control.QuestionItemControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Question_Answer.View.Control"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Question.Title}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Question.Answer}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Post code for `AddQuestionCommand` class.

Comment: do you have questions in Question collection??

Comment: Yes I have a question, "AddQuestionCommand.Execute(null);" add a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're some things need to modify in your code.

I directly make a code sample for your reference.

```
public class QuestionsViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private String description;
    public ObservableCollection<Question> questions { get; set; }
    public QuestionsViewModel()
    {
        questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
        questions.CollectionChanged += Questions_CollectionChanged;
        questions.Add(new Question("t1","a1"));


    }

    private void Questions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Description = String.Format("{0} question(s)", e.NewItems.Count);
    }



    public String Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }
}

public class QuestionViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private Question question;

    public QuestionViewModel()
    {
    }
    public Question Question
    {
        get { return question; }
        set
        {
            question = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Question");
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<UserControl
x:Class="AppMvvm2.QuestionItemControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppMvvm2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Answer}" />
</Grid>
```

```
<UserControl
x:Class="AppMvvm2.QuestionsControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppMvvm2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:QuestionsViewModel></local:QuestionsViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<StackPanel Margin="0 50 0 0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
    <ItemsControl Name="Questions" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding questions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:QuestionItemControl></local:QuestionItemControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

```
<Page
x:Class="AppMvvm2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppMvvm2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <local:QuestionsControl></local:QuestionsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did the "QuestionItemControl" like that before, but the problem is that the context is a Question and not a QuestionViewModel. To displaying fields it's ok but if I want to add logic like edit or delete a question, I can't do it from the model directly. My problem is how have a QuestionViewModel with the current Question as a datacontext for my user control "QuestionItemControl"

Comment: @PortePoisse Jerryway's way is correct. You should come up with any other method to access, viewmodel's command in Model level.. like You can bind the commands using RelativeSource binding. or any better way comes to your mind..

Answer (score 1):

A *target* property that you want to bind something *to* should be a dependency property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties

But what you should do here is to let the QuestionItemControl inherit the DataContext from its parent element in the ItemsControl. Just avoid setting the DataContext property of the QuestionItemControl explicitly in the ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl Name="Questions" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Question">
            <uc:QuestionItemControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

...and bind directly to the Title and Answer properties in QuestionItemControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Question_Answer.View.Control.QuestionItemControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Question_Answer.View.Control"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Answer}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This should work since the DataContext of each QuestionItemControl is actually a `Question` object in the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl.

Comment: Thx, so finally i should not have a view model for the QuestionItemControl ? Because that's what blocks me...

Comment: Yes. It should simply inherit its DataContext which it does by default.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i will use a collection of QuestionViewModel instead of Question. That will probably imply to synchronize the Question collection with the QuestionViewModel...